# Django inner join on self. Is there a more efficient approach?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model to track followers. This is a similar idea to every other social network site out there.

Right now my model looks like this.

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='follower')
    following = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='following')
    follow_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Today I went to add some functionality that requires a mutual relationship. Person a follows b and b follows a. I wanted the current logged in user included as well so I used Q.

```
mutual_follows_qs = Follow.objects.raw('select o.* from follow o ' + \
                                       'inner join follow f ' + \
                                       'on o.following_id = f.follower_id' + \
                                       ' and o.follower_id = f.following_id' + \
                                       ' where o.follower_id = %s', [str(request.user.pk)])
mutual_follows = []
for mutual_follow in mutual_follows_qs:
    mutual_follows.append(mutual_follow.following.pk)
possible_users = User.objects.filter(Q(pk__in=mutual_follows) \
                                      | Q(pk=request.user.pk)).order_by('username')
```

I am executing more than one query. Yuck. I am building a list from my raw to use in `Q(pk__in=mutual_follows)`. Yuck. I am curious what suggestions people have to improve the efficiency of this logic.

Here is the `UserProfile` model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
    follow = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank = True, 
                                    symmetrical=False, through='Follow')
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you are trying to achieve, but if I'm getting it right you want all users for which `Follow` object exists where `request.use` is the follower and one where `request.user` is followed (I think the `related_names` are a bit confusing).

In you source code you use an`UserProfile` and a `User` model, not sure if that's a typo or intentional, but assuming there's just the `User` model this might work:

```
user = request.user
users = User.objects.filter(
    Q(Q(follower__follower=user) & Q(following__following=user)) |
    Q(pk=user.pk))).distinct()
```

Comment: I have always been a bit confused on what I should put on my related names, apologies they're confusing. I guess I didn't add the UserProfile model to my question but I have now updated it. Pretending the Follow table has only two records, there would be one saying follower = a, following = b, and another saying follower = b, following = a. The fact these two records exist means they both follow each other. I think using your code would say the user is following herself.  Does my updated post and comment help clarify? Thanks for your help.

Comment: No it doesn't say he's following himself... The relations (follower/following) are actually a set of objects (the reverse reltion for the foreign key, a 1:n relation), so a filter like `follower__follower=user` means something like that "in this set of follow records exists one objects where the field `follower = user`"...

Comment: Ok. Gotcha. `Q(Q(follower__following=user) & Q(following__follower=user))` does it. At least that gives me the expected results where the initial gives only user. Thank you.

Comment: Some addition: If you're interested in the SQL Django generates you can do something like `print users.query`... If your tables are getting big this join will not be very efficient... And use `distinct()` for queries that generate inner joins as results can appear more than once then..